# Should I use claims to reflect an authorized user with no special roles, and if so, how?

Tags: asp.net, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm currently using ADFS and claims-based identity in ASP.NET web applications to convey informations such as a user's name or identifier.

In addition, inside applications a [ClaimsTransformer](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/claims-transformation-and-authorization-policy-in-aspnet5-mvc6) adds a couple more claims that are relevant to that app. Such claims include applicative roles (Admin, Validator, etc.), whereby the user can't see some pages unless they have the right role.

However, just because you have no role doesn't mean you can't access the application at all. Vanilla users that aren't part of a specific group are sometimes also able to see some pages. Besides, we have a few web applications where roles aren't used -- it's just a matter of whether you can get in or not. We call this "*access*", which is different from "*role*" or "*permission*".

Access rights to applications are stored in a separate database. You can have access to an application if an admin manually granted it to you or if you satisfy a set of rules calculated by another system.

How would you materialize *access* in terms of claims? A claim type like `HasAccess` with a true/false value sounds weird and vague.

Is claims-based identity the right place to look at? The idea is to insert that information precisely enough in the authorization chain that every auth cookie doesn't have to carry a list of all accessible applications for the user, but early enough in the process that an accessibility check doesn't have to be done at each http request.

Comment: Authorization may not be best placed in claims - you might be better looking up access rights for a particular user on the server side.